# My primary Gmail has several other Gmail accounts connected. One of them is sending my primary a copy of every outgoing message it sends

Tags: gmail

This is probably some setting in there that I just haven't been able to get my eyeballs on sufficiently, but it just kinda started happening out of the blue and it's just... such... a minor inconvenience!

Several other Gmail addresses also attached in what I think is the exact same way (there's some room for me to be wrong about that) are not infected with the particular secondary in questions over excitement to show me what he just sent.

Answer (score 1):

- log in to your account that is misbehaving
- goto Gmail settings/forwarding - **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop**
- correct it as you need so

[image]